# Javascript style variables with "-" in their name aren't able to be changed?

Tags: javascript

Okay, so this bug has cost me quite a bit of time and embarrassment. It seems that any style variable with a - in it's name can't be modified by javascript.

As seen here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Class Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            body { text-align: center; background-color: #ffffff;}
            #box { position: absolute; left: 610px; top: 80px; height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: #ff0000; color: #000000;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var box = 0;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box" ></div> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            box = document.getElementById('box');
            box.style.background-color = "#0000ff";
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The box in said example will just remain red.

So how do I change a style variable with a - in it's name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`backgroundColor`, camelCase.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll accept this answer just as soon at it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

`background-color` literally means "the value in background, minus the value in color"

You want `backgroundColor`

[More info...](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html)